# Explanation for observed short while winding coil around iron core

Tags: electromagnetism

I'm winding a coil, 230 turns #23 enameled magnet wire on a 1/2" diameter solid iron core 6" long ( on a lathe, hand feeding the wire )

When finished, I check continuity ( wire to rod ) with a multi-tester.

Tester shows wire is shorted to the core. OK I must have cut through the enamel.

Wind a new one (super careful this time) testing the continuity every 25 turns, after 50 turns shows shorted again.

Comment: "Tester shows wire is shorted to the core. OK I must have cut through the enamel." Correct. So what are you asking, exactly? Presumably, winding the coil on the lathe (too quickly?) is being too rough on the enamelled wire. Try winding it by hand - only 230 turns won't take  a long time.

Answer (score 0):

Wrapped paper around a new core, wrapped by hand, no short.

Has to be poor technique, or bad wire insulation.

Mystery solved.

Comment: could be poor quality wire? or you exceeded bend radius?